# How does the MSDTC log file (MSDTC.LOG) work?

Tags: sql, msdtc, distributed-transactions

Recently I encountered an error :
**The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction**

It was mentioned in one of the replies in a [forum](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1170215-146-1.aspx) , that one of the reasons could possibly be -

**The maximum number of active transactions that the MS DTC log file can accomodate has been exceeded. You must increase the size of the MS DTC log file if you wish to initiate more concurrent transactions.**

So, I am curious how the logging for MS DTC works.
 1.  Is it per Distributed Transaction and every time the transaction ends the file is cleaned up?
OR
 2. Is it like all the logs of transactions persist and the file grows over time?(Till it reaches the max file size limit set for the MSDTC.log file)

I changed the file capacity from 4MB to 16MB and noticed that the file size Immediately increased, so I am guessing 1.

But it would be wonderful if someone could explain how this **"logging"** works in detail.

Note : 
I have a fair idea of how MS DTC works.